# Cannot use any-object as KeySerializer in RedisCacheConfiguration

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-cache

An older set of code had configured a `RedisCacheManager` against a `RedisTemplate` for number of caches used in the product. In particular the Templates would frequently declare key-serializers for non-strings types, such as:

```
<property name="keySerializer">
    <bean class="org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer">
        <constructor-arg value="java.lang.Long"/>
    </bean>
</property>
```

(or sometimes UUID). When looking to upgrade / convert to a more current version of Springboot with `RedisCacheManagerBuilder`, it seems the only way to configure serializers is via `RedisCacheConfiguration` which is hard-coded to take a `SerializationPair<String>` for keys.

Is there a reason for this force-typing to String?

Comment: I'm also wondering why key type is hardcoded to String. 
Still cannot find a solution for `Could not read JSON: Cannot find a (Map) Key deserializer for type` error when using a custom object for Map key. :

Comment: Any insights as to why are keys forced to be of type String?